# Show the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the standard basis of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L: P_3 \to P_3$ be the linear transformation defined by:

$L(a + bt + ct^2 + dt 3 ) = (a − c + d) + (b + d)t + (2c − 2a − 2d)t^2 + (2b + 2d)t^3$

Show that the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the (ordered) basis $B = \{1, t, t^2 , t^3 \}$ is given by:

$A$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\-2 & 0 & 2 &-2\\0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

I approached it by taking the span of $L$ and I naturally arrived at matrix $A$.
The problem is I don't know how to show it step-by-step to show the rationale of how I got matrix $A$.

How do I do it in the context of linear transformations?

Comment: *How* did you arrive at matrix $A$?

Comment: By getting the span of $L$. It would be $L$ = $a$  $\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ + $b$  $\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ + $c$  $\begin{bmatrix} -1  \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ + $d$  $\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$. Compounded together would be matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

A linear transformation is (uniquely) determined by its action on a basis, in the sense that if $\mathcal{B}=\{e_1,..,e_n\}$ is a basis for vector space $V$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation, then the matrix $A$ of the transformation $T$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is given by $A=[T(e_1)\,T(e_2)\,\cdots\,T(e_n)]$, where the $T(e_i)$ are column vectors (written with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, of course).

So look at what the linear transformation does to the basis elements. Notice, for example, that if you let your $L$ act on the basis polynomial $e_1=1,$ you get exactly the first column of your matrix $A$.